# Name .zip file created by JSZip

Tags: javascript, zip, jszip

I am using [JSZip](https://stuk.github.io/jszip/) and I am creating a .zip file with several .xml files inside it as shown below:

```
// get each xml in string format and add it to zip object
let zip = new JSZip();
for(let i = 0; i < containers.length; i++){
    let xml = getXML(i);
    zip.file("file"+i+".xml", xml);
}

// download the .zip file
zip.generateAsync({
    type: "base64"
}).then(function(content) {
    window.location.href = "data:application/zip;base64," + content;
});
```

The .zip file is created and downloaded perfectly but the name of the file is the default "download file". What i want to do is **give a name to this file at will** (for example **allXMLs.zip**).

I looked at the JSZip documentation but I did not find anything really enlightening, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: On the page you linked, the example's function `saveAs` has a second parameter, which is the file name. So I would think you need to write the file out to disk in order to name it.

Comment: Hi Tanner, the `saveAs` function belongs to `FileSaver.js` which I do not currently have included on my project, I wonder if there is a way without including it

Comment: `FileSaver.saveAs` just creates an `<a>` element and sets it's `download` attribute. @JordanBurnett has [posted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56652494/402037) the short version of it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could create an anchor tag with a 'download' attribute that would allow you some control over the filename.

```
zip.generateAsync({
    type: "base64"
}).then(function(content) {
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = "data:application/zip;base64," + content;
    link.download = "your-file-name.zip";
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
    document.body.removeChild(link);
});
```

Comment: Hi Jordan, thanks for your response, indeed creating an anchor tag with download attribute would give me control over the filename but I was wondering whether the library itself had any out-of-the-box solution for this, in any case your suggestion is very helpful.. +1 :)

Comment: A quick look at `fileSaver.js` shows this is also the method they use :)

Comment: @NickAth _"but I was wondering whether the library itself had any out-of-the-box solution"_ -> No: https://github.com/Stuk/jszip/blob/master/documentation/howto/write_zip.md

Comment: @Andreas thanks for your response, I will follow the temporary anchor tag way instead of including a whole library on my system as Jordan suggested

Answer (score 0):

In the documentation, it suggests an additional library called [FileSaver.js].[1](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js) See [here](https://stuk.github.io/jszip/documentation/howto/write_zip.html) for the example given in the projects How To.

Comment: [Help Center - Answering -> Provide context for links](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer): _"Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. **Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline**."_